# unable to create superuser in django getting error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user"

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I am unable to create superuser in django.

Things I have done till now:

1. Created Django Project
2. Created Django App
3. Went to settings.py added the app name in installed apps list
4. Successfully able to runsever
5. Tried creating a superuser using the command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Error received :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

It would be very nice if someone could instruct me how to fix it.

Comment: You need to run migrations - `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. : answer was posted by "michjnich" in comments so copy/pasting  it here

You need to run migrations -

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user` shows you don't have a table in your database  named auth_user or has not applied some migrations since django comes with migrations that haven't been applied.

so in order to apply these migrations you need to run the command

`python manage.py migrate`

To apply the migrations and your good to proceed with your superuser creation